# JMeter WebDriver - Unable to find an element

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

```
<div id="orgData" data-bind="with: orgData"></div>
<div id="page" class="page">
<header id="header" class="header-container">
<div class="message-area" data-bind="with: statusboard.dynamicMessageArea, css: { 'has-message': statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.rotatingCalls().length > 0,
'code': (statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCode()) || (statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isEmergency() && statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCallRedColor() == true) ,
'callBlueColor': statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCode() && statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCodeBlueColor() == true,
'callOrangeColor': statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isEmergency() && statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isEmergencyOrangeColor() == true && statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCode() === false}">
<div id="dmaCallIcon" class="header-container__message-icon icon" data-bind="css: { 'call-code': displayedCall().iconState() === 1, 'call-emergency': displayedCall().iconState() === 2 }"></div>
<div>
<div class="message-area__call ellipsis" id="dmaCall" data-bind="text: displayedCall().name"></div>
<p class="message-area__spacer">&bull; </p>
<div class="message-area__room ellipsis" id="dmaLocation" data-bind="text: displayedCall().activeLocation().displayName() + ', ' + displayedCall().unit().longName()"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
<div class="units" data-bind="with: dialogHelper.configSettingsDialog.model.unitSelector">
<div class="selectedUnits">
<div>
<p><span id="labelSavedSelections" data-bind="visible: savedUnits().length > 0, text: savedUnits().length + ' of ' + availableUnitsInSavedCampus().length + ' units'"></span></p>
<p data-bind="visible: savedUnits().length == 0" id="labelNoSelections">NO UNITS SELECTED</p>
</div>
<div>
<p class="selectedCampus" data-bind="visible: savedCampusName().length > 0 ,text: savedCampusName" id="labelSelectedCampus"></p>
<p data-bind="visible: savedCampusName().length == 0" id="labelNoCampusSelections">NO CAMPUS SELECTED</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="views" data-bind="css: dialogHelper.savedViewClass">
<div>
<a id="savedViewButton" href="#" data-bind="click: dialogHelper.showSavedViewMenu">
<i class="icon savedViews">
<i class="icon changes" data-bind="css: { 'hidden': !globalHelper.unsavedChanges() }"></i>
</i>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="settings">
<a id="settingsButton" href="#" data-bind="click: dialogHelper.showSettingsMenu">
<i class="icon settings"></i>
</a>
</div>
<div class="logo">
<img src="/statusboard/svg/hr-logo-blue-no-tag.svg" />
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

From the above Page source, I need to wait for an element "settingsButton" to load. Then click on it.

I tried with

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector('main-body.application-unavailable')))
```

and

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id('settingsButton')))
```

But it doesn't works as expected. My script times out throwing an error message.

Am I missing something here? Please help.

Thanks for your support.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is capable of finding the element using the code snippet you've provided.

You can check it yourself by putting the following code into [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/):

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
def html = '<div id="orgData" data-bind="with: orgData"></div>\n' +
        '<div id="page" class="page">\n' +
        '<header id="header" class="header-container">\n' +
        '<div class="message-area" data-bind="with: statusboard.dynamicMessageArea, css: { \'has-message\': statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.rotatingCalls().length > 0,\n' +
        '\'code\': (statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCode()) || (statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isEmergency() && statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCallRedColor() == true) ,\n' +
        '\'callBlueColor\': statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCode() && statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCodeBlueColor() == true,\n' +
        '\'callOrangeColor\': statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isEmergency() && statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isEmergencyOrangeColor() == true && statusboard.dynamicMessageArea.displayedCall().isCode() === false}">\n' +
        '<div id="dmaCallIcon" class="header-container__message-icon icon" data-bind="css: { \'call-code\': displayedCall().iconState() === 1, \'call-emergency\': displayedCall().iconState() === 2 }"></div>\n' +
        '<div>\n' +
        '<div class="message-area__call ellipsis" id="dmaCall" data-bind="text: displayedCall().name"></div>\n' +
        '<p class="message-area__spacer">&bull; </p>\n' +
        '<div class="message-area__room ellipsis" id="dmaLocation" data-bind="text: displayedCall().activeLocation().displayName() + \', \' + displayedCall().unit().longName()"></div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '<div class="controls">\n' +
        '<div class="units" data-bind="with: dialogHelper.configSettingsDialog.model.unitSelector">\n' +
        '<div class="selectedUnits">\n' +
        '<div>\n' +
        '<p><span id="labelSavedSelections" data-bind="visible: savedUnits().length > 0, text: savedUnits().length + \' of \' + availableUnitsInSavedCampus().length + \' units\'"></span></p>\n' +
        '<p data-bind="visible: savedUnits().length == 0" id="labelNoSelections">NO UNITS SELECTED</p>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '<div>\n' +
        '<p class="selectedCampus" data-bind="visible: savedCampusName().length > 0 ,text: savedCampusName" id="labelSelectedCampus"></p>\n' +
        '<p data-bind="visible: savedCampusName().length == 0" id="labelNoCampusSelections">NO CAMPUS SELECTED</p>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '<div class="views" data-bind="css: dialogHelper.savedViewClass">\n' +
        '<div>\n' +
        '<a id="savedViewButton" href="#" data-bind="click: dialogHelper.showSavedViewMenu">\n' +
        '<i class="icon savedViews">\n' +
        '<i class="icon changes" data-bind="css: { \'hidden\': !globalHelper.unsavedChanges() }"></i>\n' +
        '</i>\n' +
        '</a>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '<div class="settings">\n' +
        '<a id="settingsButton" href="#" data-bind="click: dialogHelper.showSettingsMenu">\n' +
        '<i class="icon settings"></i>\n' +
        '</a>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '<div class="logo">\n' +
        '<img src="/statusboard/svg/hr-logo-blue-no-tag.svg" />\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</div>\n' +
        '</header>'
new File('page.html').text = html
WDS.browser.get('file://' + System.getProperty('user.dir') + '/page.html')
def element = WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('settingsButton'))
WDS.log.info('Settings button present: ' + element.isEnabled())
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

You should see the following line in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging):

```
INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Settings button present: true
```

So it might be the case the element you're looking for is in [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) or [Shadow Dom](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-components-shadow-dom). We need to see the **full page source** in order to be able to help.